# C++Builder 10.2 64-Bit - How to set the packet alignment?

Tags: clang, c++builder, clang++, llvm-clang

I'm busy with trying to compile a C++Builder 10.2 **32-Bit** DLL Project as a **64-Bit** DLL.

This DLL is a plugin for some other proprietary software.
Stated in the SDK for this application is:

> Set the “Struct Member Alignment” for the 64‐bit version of your
>   project to 8 byte.

Because I don't want to touch the SDK's header files, I need a way to tell **BCC64** to use an alignment of **8 Bytes** as default.

Looking at
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/C%2B%2B_Compiler there's a table for those compiler options but for **BCC64** unfortunately there are just *N/A*'s everywhere.

How can I tell C++Builder's 64-Bit Compiler to use that packing, and why does the *Clang* based BCC32c support those settings whereas the also *Clang* based BCC64 does not?

[image: Table]

Comment: Perhaps you can use a `#pragma pack(push, 8)` or similar (and a `#pragma pack(pop)` to restore)?

Comment: FWIW, I think 8 is the default packing. This should be easy to test, with a simple struct with different size integers and checking the offsets.

Comment: And, if the header files are any good, they should do that already. Just browse them for the word "pack" and see what they do.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: "*This should be easy to test, with a simple struct with different size integers and checking the offsets*" - or using [`alignof()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Alignof) instead.

Comment: @Remy: thanks. I didn't even know it was implemented. Does it work on structured types too? And does it give you the alignment required, or the actual alignment set? Yes, I know I could test that. `<g>`.